# Understanding the MIPS equivalent of this C++ code

Tags: c++, mips, mips32

How would you replicate:

```
int* a;
b = a[2];
```

In MIPS, without using `.data`?

My answer for this was: `lw $t1, 4($t0)`, where `$t0` is a & `$t1` is b--but this was incorrect.

Similarly, how would you replicate:

```
char* a;
a[4] = b;
```

Once again, my answer for this was `lb 4($s0), $t0`, where `$t0` is b & `$s0` is a--but this was also incorrect.

Comment: Technically you can do whatever you want. `a[2]` invokes undefined behaviour (there is no third element of `a`) so you could write MIPS assembly that orders a nuclear missile strike on Atlantis.

Comment: I think it's assuming that you're just grabbing the `base + offset * sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate

```
int* a;
b = a[2];
```

`a[2]` is 2 elements after what is pointed at by `a`, so `lh $t1, 4($t0)` if `int` is 2-byte long and `lw $t1, 8($t0)` if `int` is 4-byte long.

To replicate

```
char* a;
a[4] = b;
```

The instruction to write 1-byte value to memory is `sb`, not `lb`. Therefore, `sb $t0, 4($s0)` should do assuming `char` is 1-byte long.

Comment: Two questions: Wouldn't it be `sb $t0, 1($s0)`? since the char is only 1 byte, the next position would be at offset 1, right? Secondly, how is `a[4] = b` storing to memory? I thought that was for the stack pointer?

Comment: @EthanR `a[4]` is not next position but next position of next position of next position of next position of what is pointed at `a`.

Comment: Oh wait I just realized it's `a[4]`. My bad!

Comment: @EthanR `a` is a pointer, so `a[4]` is supporsed to be placed on somewhere on the memory and assigning to that will mean writing to the memory. Typically stack is also on the memory.